# SwiftUI @EnvironmentObject no ObservableObject of type error

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

I am getting the error

> Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type LoginResponse found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for LoginResponse may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

I have passed the environment object to all the subviews of LoginView(), but the error still persists

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @State var loginCredentials = Credentials()
    var loginResponse = LoginResponse()
    var dataCall = DataCall()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button(action:{self.dataCall.AttemptLogin(loginCredentials: self.loginCredentials)}){
                
                Text("LOGIN")
                
            }
            
            Text("\(self.loginResponse.jwt)")
            
        }
        .environmentObject(self.loginResponse)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the code if needed

```
struct Credentials: Encodable {
    var login: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
}

class LoginResponse: Decodable, ObservableObject {
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case success, userId, jwt
    }
    
    @Published var success: Bool = false
    @Published var userId: String = ""
    var error: String = ""
    @Published var jwt: String = ""
    init(){}
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        success = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
        userId = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .userId)
        jwt = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .jwt)
    }
}

struct DataCall {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var dataResponse : LoginResponse
    
    func AttemptLogin(loginCredentials: Credentials)  {
        
        let loginResponse = LoginResponse()
        dataResponse.success = loginResponse.success
        
        }
}
```

Comment: This is not how you implement views in SwiftUI. Don't store them as variables. I recommend you watch some [Apple tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) first and see how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `DataCall` is not a SwiftUI view, I don't believe you can use the `.environmentObject` modifier to pass data to it. Instead, just add a reference to a `LoginResponse` object in the `DataCall` struct, and pass it through the constructor like normal.

Example:

```
struct DataCall {
  weak var dataResponse : LoginResponse
  ...
}

let dataCall = DataCall(dataResponse: loginResponse)
```

However, I'm pretty confused about your view design. Any object that you declare normally in a View, without `@State` or `@ObservedObject`, will be recreated over and over again. Is that what you want?